# Trying to Prove Distributive Laws with Respect to Set Difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to prove the following two statements:

1. $A \cap(B-C)=(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$
2. $(A-C)\cap (B-C)=(A\cap B)-C$

And I have a proof, which I want to make sure is correct for (1) in one direction (which if correct then I can do in the other direction similarly), but I'm very unsure for (2). My proof for (1) is as follows: 
Let $x\in A \cap (B-C) $. 
$\Rightarrow$ $x \in A $ $\land$ $x\in(B-C) $ 
$\Rightarrow$ $x \in A $ $\land$ $(x\in B$ $\land$ $ x\notin C) $ 
$\Rightarrow$ $(x \in A$ $\land$ $x\in B)$  $\land$ $(x\in A$ $\land$ $ x\notin C) $ 
$\Rightarrow$ $(x \in A \cap B)$  $\land$ $(x\notin A \cap C) $ 
$\Rightarrow$ $x\in (A \cap B)$  $-$ $(A \cap C) $ 
And the reverse direction also follows (if true), which means 
$ A \cap(B-C) \subseteq (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$ and 
$  (A\cap B)-(A\cap C) \subseteq A \cap(B-C) $ 
$\Rightarrow A \cap(B-C)=(A\cap B)-(A\cap C) $.

My proof for (2), is:

Let $x\in (A-C)\cap (B-C)$ 
$\Rightarrow x\in (A-C)$ $\land$ $x\in (B-C) $ 
$\Rightarrow (x\in A$ $\land$ $x\notin C$ ) $\land$ $(x\in B$ $\land$ $x\notin C)$ 
$\Rightarrow (x\in A$ $\land$ $x\in B$$)$ $\land$ $x\notin C$ 
$\Rightarrow x\in (A \cap B)$ $\land$ $x\notin C$ 
$\Rightarrow x\in (A \cap B) - C$ 
and similarly, the reverse direction also follows, which means
$ (A-C)\cap (B-C) \subseteq (A\cap B)-C$ and 
$  (A\cap B)-C \subseteq (A-C)\cap (B-C)$ 
$(A-C)\cap (B-C)=(A\cap B)-C$.

I'm quite new to this and I've been trying to teach myself for only about a week so please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof for (2)

$x \in (A - C) \cap (B - C)$

$(x \in A \wedge x \notin C) \wedge (x \in B \wedge x \notin C)$

Recalling $\wedge$ is commutative and associative as well as $(x \notin C) \wedge (x \notin C) = (x \notin C)$

$(x \in A \wedge x \in B) \wedge (x \notin C)$

$x \in (A \cap B) - C$

Comment: I realized this as well after a bit, but thank you for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x\in U\cap W$ stands for $x\in U$ and $x\in W$.

Consider any $x\in (A-C)\cap (B-C)$. Then $x\in A-C$ and $x\in B-C$, i.e., $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ but $x\notin C$. Thus, $x\in (A\cap B)-C$.

Next, let $x\in (A\cap B)-C$, which implies $x\in A\cap B$ but $x\notin C$. Therefore, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ but $x\notin C$, i.e., $x\in A-C$ and $x\in B-C$. Thus, $x\in (A-C)\cap (B-C)$.